# Display complete subreport instead of preview in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have a crystal report with a basic sub report that I will have users generate and export. The problem is the exported document isn't exporting the complete sub report, just the preview. Is there a way around this? The only thing I've found close to it is removing the borders from the sub report object but it still displays off center and is clickable in the reportviewer (something else I'd like to avoid, if at all possible).

I understand I can click the sub report, export that, and export the main report but that will make training my users quite a bit more taxing.

Exported
[image]

Actual
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by clickable?

Comment: When the report viewer loads, it displays the report and preview of the sub report. the preview is clickable. When you click it, it opens the sub report in it's own tab within the report viewer.